# Paste range with offset

Tags: excel, vba, range, paste

First post here, this site has helped me a lot in the past. Not an expert, I basically take existing code and adapt them to what I need... I know I need to learn more.

For a daily report, I want to take a set of data and paste it to another sheet, for a specific date. The code I had was (shortened, rest is the same, about 200 times)

```
Sub FileToDatabase_Click()

Dim selectedDate As String
Dim rangeFound As Range
selectedDate = Sheets("Input").Range("L3")
Set rangeFound = Sheets("Report").Cells.Find(CDate(selectedDate))

‘Insert 101 assays parameters
Dim Pb101 As Double
Dim Zn101 As Double
Dim Cu101 As Double
Dim Fe101 As Double
Dim Ag101 As Double
Pb101 = Sheets("Input").Range("D25")
Zn101 = Sheets("Input").Range("E25")
Cu101 = Sheets("Input").Range("F25")
Fe101 = Sheets("Input").Range("G25")
Ag101 = Sheets("Input").Range("H25")

If IsEmpty(rangeFound.Offset(0, 1)) = True Then

rangeFound.Offset(0, 2) = Pb101
rangeFound.Offset(0, 3) = Zn101
rangeFound.Offset(0, 4) = Cu101
rangeFound.Offset(0, 5) = Fe101
rangeFound.Offset(0, 6) = Ag101

End If
End Sub
```

This code works, but with >200 values it takes a long time. So what I was thinking is to put formulas in my "Input" sheet to put my data in the right order, and move that row to the correct date on my "report" sheet. The "input" sheet has a table and some simple calculations.

Digging on this site, I guess I would probably need something like:

```
Sub Normalize()

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A65").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A66").Value

End Sub
```

I am not sure how I can set my range on the second sheet to match the right date.

Thanks

Comment: hmm .. seems like you can achieve the same with just a bunch of VLookup functions

Comment: This is what we used to have. With a different tab every day for the input. But the "report" data are fetched on another file. And the hundreds of tabs slow down/crash the process. Which is why we want to have a new workbook with the "input" sheet cleared every day.

Comment: `rangeFound.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 5).Value = Sheets("Input").Range("D25:H25").Value`. Might be easier to join them with Power Query or Microsoft Query

Comment: In my case it would be: rangeFound.Offset(0, 2).Resize(0, 206).Value = Sheets("Input").Range("A70:GZ70").Value    Like this I have an error, if I remove the resize part I only get the first value of the range.

Comment: you cannot resize to zero! and you must equal the ranges sizes. For instance: `rangeFound.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 207).Value = Sheets("Input").Range("A70:GZ70").Value`, since columns A to GZ are 207 columns

Comment: Hum... tried it again and it worked. Thanks Slai

Comment: If your goal is to speed this up, this is a good first step.  However, you should also define variables for repeated references like `Sheets("Input")` as that has to retrieve the sheet reference from the Sheets collection via a lookup on the value "Input".  Also try to restrict the Range.Find to search only the UsedRange for the Report sheet.